# Migrations to AWS OpenSearch from ElasticSearch version 2.4

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, opensearch

What is the migration path to move  from self-managed EasticSearch version 2.4 (Basic - Elastic.co) to AWS managed OpenSearch ? One approach i can think of is using LogStack. Looking for your suggestions.

Comment: I don't think you can migrate from version 2.4 to opensearch. You can check the migration path here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/version-migration.html. Once you have version 6.8 or above, you can make a new snapshot, save in s3, create an opensearch domani and restore the snapshot in the new domain.

Comment: If you have to minimize downtime you can try to upgrade 2.4 -> 5.6 -> 6.8 -> 7.16 but it will take a long time and you'll probably have to update data schema, there are some breaking changes. I'd say use something like [Elasticsearch-dump](https://github.com/elasticsearch-dump/elasticsearch-dump) to dump your old data and then restore into a new cluster.